# Axisymmetric blockMeshDict: FOAM FATAL ERROR: wedge ... centre plane does not align with a coordinate plane by

Tags: mesh, openfoam

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Main_ContribExamples/AxiSymmetric)  to create the axisymmetric model below:

> [image]

Following the discussions over [here](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-meshing-blockmesh/205599-creating-axisymmetric-piston-cylinder-blockmeshdict.html), my `blockMeshDict` file is:

```
FoamFile
{
    version     2.0;
    format      ascii;
    class       dictionary;
    object      blockMeshDict;
}

convertToMeters 0.001;

wa 5.0;
cr 10.0;
pr 8.0;
cl 50.0;
px 20.0; 
pl 10.0; 
px2 #calc "$px+$pl"; 
ms 50; 

vertices
(
    (0                      0                         0)    //00
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$pr*sin($wa/2)"    0)    //01
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$pr*sin($wa/2)"   0)    //02
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$pr*sin($wa/2)"   $px)  //03
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$pr*sin($wa/2)"    $px)  //04
    (0                      0                         $px)  //05
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$cr*sin($wa/2)"    $px)  //06
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$cr*sin($wa/2)"    0)    //07
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$cr*sin($wa/2)"   0)    //08
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$cr*sin($wa/2)"   $px)  //09
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$cr*sin($wa/2)"   $px2) //10
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$cr*sin($wa/2)"    $px2) //11
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$pr*sin($wa/2)"    $px2) //12
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$pr*sin($wa/2)"   $px2) //13
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$pr*sin($wa/2)"   $cl)  //14
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$pr*sin($wa/2)"    $cl)  //15
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$cr*sin($wa/2)"    $cl)  //16
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$cr*sin($wa/2)"   $cl)  //17
    (0                      0                         $cl)  //18
    (0                      0                         $px2) //19
);

blocks
(
    hex (0  1  2  0  5  4  3  5)         ($ms 1 $ms) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
    hex (1  7  8  2  4  6  9  3)         ($ms 1 $ms) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
    hex (4  6  9  3  12 11 10 13)        ($ms 1 $ms) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
    hex (12 11 10 13 15 16 17 14)        ($ms 1 $ms) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
    hex (19 12 13 19 18 15 14 18)        ($ms 1 $ms) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
);

edges
(
);

boundary
(
    inlet
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (0 1 2 0)
            (1 7 8 2)
        );
    }
    outlet
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (18 15 14 18)
            (15 16 17 14)
        );
    }
    walls
    {
        type wall;
        faces
        (
            (7  8  9  6)
            (6  9  10 11)
            (11 10 17 16)
        );
    }
    wedgeBack
    {
        type wedge;
        faces
        (
            (0  1  4  5)
            (1  7  6  4)
            (4  6  11 12)
            (12 11 16 15)
            (19 12 15 18)
        );
    }

    wedgeFront
    {
        type wedge;
        faces
        (
            (0  2  3  5)
            (2  8  9  3)
            (3  9  10 13)
            (13 10 17 14)
            (19 13 14 18)
        );
    }

    axis
     { 
           type empty;
           faces  
           (
               (0  5  5  0)
               (19 18 18 19)
           );
    }
);

mergePatchPairs
(
);
```

But when i run the `blockMesh` I get the warnings like:

> Creating block mesh topology
>   --> FOAM Warning :
>      From function Foam::polyMesh::polyMesh(const Foam::IOobject&, const Foam::Xfer > >&, const cellShapeList&, const faceListList&, const wordList&, const Foam::PtrList&, const Foam::word&, const Foam::word&, bool)
>           in file meshes/polyMesh/polyMeshFromShapeMesh.C at line 871
>       Found 3 undefined faces in mesh; adding to default patch.

followed by the error:

> --> FOAM FATAL ERROR:
>   wedge wedgeFront centre plane does not align with a coordinate plane by 0.360319
>   From function virtual void Foam::wedgePolyPatch::calcGeometry(Foam::PstreamBuffers&)
>       in file meshes/polyMesh/polyPatches/constraint/wedge/wedgePolyPatch.C at line 98.

unfortunately Googling the error message doesn't return [much](https://www.google.nl/search?newwindow=1&ei=k_N9W8jhKNDSkwWXpKHoCQ&q=FOAM%20FATAL%20ERROR%20wedge%20%22centre%20plane%20does%20not%20align%20with%20a%20coordinate%20plane%20by%22&oq=FOAM%20FATAL%20ERROR%20wedge%20%22centre%20plane%20does%20not%20align%20with%20a%20coordinate%20plane%20by%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1.8641.16137.0.16734.2.2.0.0.0.0.50.93.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.93....0.HvFrsBGHHKA). I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Comment: Googling the error message might or might not help with OpenFOAM, however, I find OpenFOAM's error messages quite telling and useful. It tells you exactly what is wrong, although, I have to admit, for the newcomer, including myself, they are sometimes hard to read. But given enough experience, OpenFOAM's error messages are really helpful.

Comment: BTW: [the Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openfoam) SE site is the more common place to post OpenFOAM related questions. I have no idea how this is done, yet I propose to migrate the question to SciComp SE.

Comment: @DohnJoe I will try your code and come back here. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @DohnJoe I tried computational science stackexchange for my [new question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/30080/implementing-brent-solver-instead-of-newton-method-in-thermoi-h-to-resolve-maxim). did not get much help though!

Comment: Well, OpenFOAM is a very specific topic. So, don't expect immediate answers. Unfortunately, the OpenFOAM community is rather small.

Answer (score 2):

The way you compute the point coordinates seems quite weird to me, e.g. what is the parameter `wa` supposed to mean? It seems that you intended it to be an angle.

I managed to get a valid mesh by changing the patch type of the wedge patches to the type `patch`, which is more forgiving than the type `wegde`. I do this frequently when trouble-shooting blockMeshDicts.

Furthermore, I changed the order of the vertices in the inlet patch definition. The vertex list in a patch definition has to adhere the "right-hand rule", see the [User Guide](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/v6-blockMesh/#x25-1890005.3.5).

For cases employing axi-symmetry, the [User Guide](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/v6-boundaries/#x24-1730005.2) recommends having a small wedge angle, e.g. 1°, for the axi-symmetric domain. This is most probably the reason behind your error stating that the wedge centre plane doesn't align.

Thus, I propose:

- Keep the wedge patches as being of the type `patch` for the time being
- Sort out your geometry, so that you are able to produce a 1° slice of geometry
- Change the wedge patches back to `wedge`, once your geometry is a 1° slice

[image: The block structure]

```
FoamFile
{
    version     2.0;
    format      ascii;
    class       dictionary;
    object      blockMeshDict;
}

convertToMeters 0.001;

wa 4.0;
cr 10.0;
pr 8.0;
cl 50.0;
px 20.0; 
pl 10.0; 
px2 #calc "$px+$pl"; 
ms 50; 

vertices
(
    (0                      0                         0)    //00
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$pr*sin($wa/2)"    0)    //01
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$pr*sin($wa/2)"   0)    //02
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$pr*sin($wa/2)"   $px)  //03
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$pr*sin($wa/2)"    $px)  //04
    (0                      0                         $px)  //05
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$cr*sin($wa/2)"    $px)  //06
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$cr*sin($wa/2)"    0)    //07
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$cr*sin($wa/2)"   0)    //08
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$cr*sin($wa/2)"   $px)  //09
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$cr*sin($wa/2)"   $px2) //10
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$cr*sin($wa/2)"    $px2) //11
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$pr*sin($wa/2)"    $px2) //12
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$pr*sin($wa/2)"   $px2) //13
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$pr*sin($wa/2)"   $cl)  //14
    (#calc "$pr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$pr*sin($wa/2)"    $cl)  //15
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "$cr*sin($wa/2)"    $cl)  //16
    (#calc "$cr*cos($wa/2)" #calc "-$cr*sin($wa/2)"   $cl)  //17
    (0                      0                         $cl)  //18
    (0                      0                         $px2) //19
);

blocks
(
    hex (0  1  2  0  5  4  3  5)         ($ms 1 $ms) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
    hex (1  7  8  2  4  6  9  3)         ($ms 1 $ms) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
    hex (4  6  9  3  12 11 10 13)        ($ms 1 $ms) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
    hex (12 11 10 13 15 16 17 14)        ($ms 1 $ms) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
    hex (19 12 13 19 18 15 14 18)        ($ms 1 $ms) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
);

edges
(
);

boundary
(
    inlet
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (0 2 1 0)
            (1 2 8 7)
        );
    }
    outlet
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (18 15 14 18)
            (15 16 17 14)
        );
    }
    walls
    {
        type wall;
        faces
        (
            (7  8  9  6)
            (6  9  10 11)
            (11 10 17 16)
        );
    }
    wedgeBack
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (0  1  4  5)
            (1  7  6  4)
            (4  6  11 12)
            (12 11 16 15)
            (19 12 15 18)
        );
    }

    wedgeFront
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (0  2  3  5)
            (2  8  9  3)
            (3  9  10 13)
            (13 10 17 14)
            (19 13 14 18)
        );
    }

    axis
     { 
           type empty;
           faces  
           (
               (0  5  5  0)
               (19 18 18 19)
           );
    }
);

mergePatchPairs
(
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. some points: 1. wa stands for wedge angle and I considered as 5 as told in [this page](https://www.openfoam.com/documentation/user-guide/boundaries.php), is it better if we consider it smaller or closer to 5? 2. it doesn't affect the solution if we change wedge to patch? 3. the normal to every face must be outwards? or all of them should be in the same direction? this is really confusing!

Comment: Note, that what you enter in the trigonometric functions is an angle in radians, not degrees. Because of this, I was only able to create a valid mesh with values of wa=4 and wa=5.

Comment: aaaah, the common undergrad mistake! I will fix this now. it is indeed 5 degrees!

Comment: The wedge patches have to be of the type `wedge`, once you run your simulation, yet for trouble-shooting the mesh setting them to the type `patch` makes mesh generation more forgiving. The image I posted is with the wedge patches having the type `patch`, if I would set them to be of the  `wedge` type, mesh generation would fail, and I would not be able to see the block-structure.

Comment: The patches are defined in a way, so that the face normal points outwards. The [Right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) is very useful for this purpose. Point your thumb in a way, so it points outwards; and then follow your index finger around the patch boundary to visit all vertices.

Comment: The User Guide: _The order in which the vertices are given must be such that, looking from inside the block and starting with any vertex, the face must be traversed in a clockwise direction to define the other vertices._

Comment: Is this `wa 5.0*constant::mathematical::pi/180;` a correct way of changing from degrees to radians?

Comment: There is a pre-defined function to use: `radHalfAngle    #calc "degToRad($halfAngle)";`, but what you posted should also do the trick.

Comment: shockingly enough fixing the degree-radian issue removed the above error! but now I have this error: `FOAM FATAL IO ERROR:
Block hex (0 1 2 0 5 4 3 5) (50 1 50) simpleGrading (1(1) 1(1) 1(1)) has inward-                                          pointing faces
    4(1 2 3 4) 4(0 1 4 5) 4(0 5 3 2) 4(0 0 2 1) 4(5 4 3 5)` I am gonna fix that one now.

Comment: I guess you need to revisit the block definition. I managed to create a valid block 0 with an alternative vertex-ordering `hex (0  2  1  0  5  3  4  5)`.
The error message _inward- pointing faces_ means that most probably the vertex-ordering of the block definition is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I think there are two ways to consider faces. one when defining blocks/hexs then the normal of two faces defining the hex should point to the same direction, in our case negative z. but when defining boundaries they normal should point outwards. is this true?

Comment: I fixed the normals as explained in the above comment and no wI get the error: ` FOAM FATAL ERROR:
Inconsistent number of faces between block pair 0 and 1 From function void Foam::blockMesh::calcMergeInfo() in file blockMesh/blockMeshMerge.C at line 217.`

Comment: block definition is independent of face definition.

Comment: Another trouble-shooting tip: set the number of cells to 1 for all blocks and for all directions. Once a single-cell-per-block mesh can be successfully created, then set your cell numbers to the desired values. _Inconsistent number of faces between block pair X and Y_ means, that two neighbouring, connected blocks are discretized with non-matching cell numbers.

Comment: awesome. I changed all the `$ms` mesh sizes to 1 and now it compiles. what is wrong with those though?

Comment: now I'm able to divide al the hexs in z direction without any issues, and first and last hex in x direction. the problem arises when I try to mesh 2, 3 and 4 in x direction! you may find my latest `blockMeshDict` [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/22edbd7a7bdefefc24005753c8f89d40)

Comment: weird, but I was able to divide 2, 3 and 4 hexes in x direction by changing the y parameter! you may see the updated `blockMeshDict` [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/22edbd7a7bdefefc24005753c8f89d40). I also get this warnings now: ` FOAM Warning :
    From function virtual void Foam::wedgePolyPatch::calcGeometry(Foam::PstreamBuffers&)
    in file meshes/polyMesh/polyPatches/constraint/wedge/wedgePolyPatch.C at line 70 Wedge patch 'wedgeBack' is not planar.
At local face at the normal differs from the average normal 
Either correct the patch or split it into planar parts`

Comment: from [here](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam/176129-solved-wedge-patch-not-planer-error.html#post703640) I solved the problem by changing writePrecision in controlDict file from 6 to 7! OpenFOAM is freaking weird!

Comment: Yeah, the issue with `writePrecision` is a tricky one. I had similar problems in the past. So, why does this happen? The `#calc` entries in the blockMeshDict are compiled and run to perform the computations. Any results are written to disk with the precision set by `writePrecision`. Thus, computing a point coordinate may use an intermediate result in the form of: `os << (8.000000*cos(0.017453/2));`. With too small a precision, some computations might not be accurate enough.

Comment: _divide 2, 3 and 4 hexes in x direction by changing the y parameter_
Take a good look at Figure 5.4 in the [User Guide](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/v6-blockMesh/). The local x-,y- and z- directions of an individual block are not necessarily in line with the global x-, y- and z-directions of the global coordinate system.

Comment: another weird behaviour: if I use `radHalfAngle #calc "degToRad(5)";` I get the same planar... warning, unless I change the `writePrecision` to 8 in `controlDict` file!

Comment: As I can see when you define a hex the direction from point 0 to 1 is x, from 1 to 2 is z and the one perpendicular tho these is y. Hence for 2, 3, 4 the y and z are switched!

Comment: Take another look at Figure 5.4 from the [User Guide](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/v6-blockMesh/). The edge 0-1 is the local x-direction, or x_1; the edge 1-2 is the local y-direction, or x_2; and the perpendicular direction to the two aforementioned edges is the local z-direction.

Comment: It would be great if these point could be categorized and cleaned up for future reference.